# Class 'File' is abstract;can not be instantiated

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code but get me error when click on Run button.

```
if (image is PickedFile) {
      var result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithFile(
        File(image.path).absolute.path,
        minWidth: 800,
        minHeight: 800,
        quality: quality,
        format: CompressFormat.jpeg,
      );
      base64 += base64Encode(result);
    }
```

Error :

lib/common/tools.dart:813:9: Error: The class 'File' is abstract and can't be instantiated

```
    File(image.path).absolute.path,
    ^^^^
```

Comment: Are you using `File` from `package:file` instead of from `dart:io`?  If you're using `package:file`, then you will need to instantiate its `File` object via a `FileSystem` object (e.g. `LocalFileSystem().file(image.path)`).

Comment: @jamesdlin :( im not developer, now i learning and cant know anything.

Answer (score -1):

Now , i change this line

```
        File(image.path).absolute.path,
```

to

```
        File, image.path.absolute.path,
```

and this too run without error :

```
        File, (image.path).absolute.path,
```

With this to change error fixed but i not know application work fine or not.

Comment: This makes no sense and isn't an answer.  You should try making the change that I suggested.